# fluent nhibernate in C++/ CLI

Tags: orm, fluent-nhibernate

Can we use fluent nhibernate with C++/ CLI?

If so any body knows how to make mappings in C++?

In C# :

```
public class Employee
{
  public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
  public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
  public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
  public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
  public EmployeeMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.FirstName);
    Map(x => x.LastName);
    References(x => x.Store);
  }
}
```

**BUT How to use Map in C++/CLI** ?(C++/CLI does not support => lambda expressions)
 **How can i write this in C++/ CLI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If C++/CLI doesn't support lambda expressions, then you can't use Fluent NHibernate with it; lambdas are a pretty fundamental part of Fluent NHibernate. Your only option is to create a C# project specifically for mappings, and reference that from your CLI project.